# Need help placing table at beginning of page

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am placing tables into a Word document. The number of rows in a table may vary but the row height is fixed so I know the maximum number of rows that can fit on a single page. When I reach that max number, I want to add a new page to the document and then insert a new table on it. Sounds simple but I'm running into all sorts of weird results. 
Result #1: I have tried using both "Selection.InsertNewPage" and "Selection.InsertBreak(wdPageBreak)". When I do this, 2 pages are added instead of 1.

```
 NumberOfPages = SectionObject.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
 TableLocation = TableObject.Range  'get the range object of the current table
 TableLocation.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd) 'go to end of table
 TableLocation.Select()
 WordDocument.Application.Selection.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdPageBreak) 'adds 2 pages instead of 1
 NumberOfPagesNew = SectionObject.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
```

To try to make this work I wrote this code (it doesn't work)

```
If NumberOfPagesNew > NumberOfPages + 1 Then
   TableLocation = WordDocument.Range.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, NumberOfPagesNew) 'go to last page of doc
   TableLocation.Delete() 'delete that page
   TableLocation = WordDocument.Range.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, NumberOfPagesNew - 1) 'go to new last page
   TableLocation.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart) 'move cursor to start of page
End If

'I add a new table using this code
TableObject = WordDocument.Tables.Add(TableLocation, NumberOfRowsNeeded - 1, 5)
```

But instead of placing my table on the last page, another page gets added and my table is placed on it. The end result is a page with a table, a blank page, and then another page with a table.

Result #2: Another thing I tried was moving my cursor to the end of the table, adding a line break and then placing my table after that. This got around my problem of adding 2 pages instead of 1. However, it adds 2 lines onto the new page instead of 1 which throws off my row counting code. Below is the code I used.

```
TableLocation = TableObject.Range 'get range object of current table
TableLocation.Collapse(wdCollapseEnd) 'go to end of table
TableLocation.Select()
WordDocument.Application.Selection.InsertBreak(wdLineBreak) 'should add 1 line
TableLocation = WordDocument.Application.Selection.GoToNext(wdGoToLine) 
TableLocation.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart)

'I add my next table using this code.
TableObject = WordDocument.Tables.Add(TableLocation, NumberOfRowsNeeded - 1, 5)
```

This code places my table one line lower than it should.

I don't do a lot of Word coding and I know very little about the intricacies of the selection object so I am sure that is where my problem lies. If someone could show me a good way of accomplishing what I want to do, I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,

Darren

Comment: Try this in the UI: Insert that second table after the first (you need an empty paragraph between them!) Click in the first cell of that second table, go to the Paragraph dialog launcher in the Home tab of the Ribbon, the second tab in the dialog (line and page breaks) and activate the option to start a new page. (I'm on a mobile device which is why I can't give any more exact instructions.) Does that do what you need?

Comment: Cindy, I'm doing all this through code. The UI is never opened.

Comment: I understand that. My proposal was to see if this approach works for you. If it does, it can be implemented in code. But it's much simpler to discover an optimal approach while working in the UI.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code. Make sure that the number of rows of the table allows it to fit on one page. If this does not work, try with one fewer row in the table, Word might need some extra spaces before / after the table depending on the active format.

```
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Selection.Range, 5, 5
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.InsertBreak WdBreakType.wdPageBreak
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Selection.Range, 5, 5
' ...
```

Of course, this is just to show you an approach that will work and avoids the difficulties that you experienced. You need to adapt the code to your specific task.

Comment: Code that relies on Selection is not really robust - working with Range and other objects (such as a Table) is preferable

Comment: @Darren Haverstick - Did you get a chance to try this?